# MYSQL:Where condition in Case statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have table room_category_charges with fields like

```
id room_category(id) category_charges payment_type(id)
1       1                   300              1
2       1                   600              2
3       2                   400              1
4       2                   800              2
```

and there is another table patient_detail(patient_admission) where tpa(third_party_name) is selected. Whether or not tpa name is selected the rates of payment type varies.

Accordingly I am trying to use the following mysql query using case.

I want to return the charges

1. as 600 where room_category is 1 and tpa_name is not null.
2. as 400 where room_category is 2 and tpa_name is null

SQL:

```
  select rn.room_name, 
    CASE WHEN p.tpa_name is NULL
    THEN rcc.category_charges where rcc.payment_type=1
    ELSE rcc.category_charges where rcc.payment_type=2
    END AS 'charges'
  from estimate e,patient_detail p,room_name n
```

the where clause in then and else statement is generating the error, how I can incorporate the where clause in the case statement.

Thanks.

Comment: please simplify your question by removing the irrelevant tables, and provide an example output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found one solution, which seems to be working fine. Any better solution is welcome.

```
SELECT rn.room_name, rcc.category_charges
FROM estimate e,room_category rc, room_name rn, room_category_charges rcc, patient_detail p
WHERE rn.room_category = rc.id and rcc.room_category=rc.id
AND e.alloted_bed = p.bed_type
AND rcc.payment_type =2 and e.alloted_bed=rn.id and p.tpa_name is not null

union

SELECT rn.room_name, rcc.category_charges
FROM estimate e,room_category rc, room_name rn, room_category_charges rcc, patient_detail p
WHERE rn.room_category = rc.id and rcc.room_category=rc.id
AND e.alloted_bed = p.bed_type
AND rcc.payment_type =1 and e.alloted_bed=rn.id and p.tpa_name is null
```

Answer (score 0):

`where` is a clause of the `select` statement and you cannot use it in a case operator.

The syntax of [case](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) can be as follows:

> ```
> CASE value WHEN [compare_value] THEN result [WHEN [compare_value] THEN result ...] [ELSE result] END
> CASE WHEN [condition] THEN result [WHEN [condition] THEN result ...] [ELSE result] END
> ```

As I understand the question, you might want a query like this

```
select rn.room_name, 
rcc.category_charges
from estimate e
join room_name rn on e.alloted_bed=rn.id
join patient_detail p on e.ipd_patient_id=p.ipd_patient_id
join room_category_charges rcc on rn.room_category=rcc.id and ((rcc.payment_type=1 and p.tpa_name is null) or (rcc.payment_type=2 and p.tpa_name is not null))
```

Comment: Not exactly - the room charges can vary depending on on the category. The category can be 1,2,3,4 and room_charges will change accordingly.

Comment: well, then the question does not really seem to be clear on that: only room category 1 and 2 are mentioned. do you have another table for room_charges? you could simply join then. or you can extend the case with two more when clauses for room category 3 and 4.

Comment: I have around 10 room category. is that the proper way to do that?

Comment: then it would be probably better to have another table for them instead of operating with case

Comment: or maybe, you can have another column in room_category_charges. one column for charges with tpa_name, and another one for charges without that.

Comment: Ok I will consider that

Comment: ok, probably I understand now what you mean. so payment_type is 1 when tpa_name is not null and it is 2 tpa_name is null, right? then you can use that for the join condition. I updated the query.

Comment: Exactly but that is where I am getting the error `MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where rcc.payment_type=1 `

Comment: sure, you don't need the case then, check out the updated version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69927/discussion-between-pawan-and-lp).